# Could the flagging profile be clarified?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Can we please make the flagging weight page better? When I go to my profile, and I see my flag weight has changed, I click on the flag weight button, and the thing is, I can't tell which of my flags are valid, invalid, or not yet reviewed. Could we please format it so that there are three sections?

Answer (score 3):

Hi; you might find this meta.stackoverflow discussion useful: [Please show what flags were deemed good or bad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88738/please-show-what-flags-were-deemed-good-or-bad)

But the short version — it is intentional that it isn't displayed.

- In most cases, it should be obvious from the follow-up information (deleted, edited, left-comment, etc.) if it has been enacted.
- We really value (appropriate) flagging, but often flags can be a bit subjective. As such it is not *necessarily* helpful to focus intently on any one single flag.
- The other issue is that it then creates a "hey! why was my flag rejected?" loop... Moderation takes effort by our much-valued community moderators, and we don't want to make that *worse* by having to justify every single call (again, emphasis on the *subjective* nature). Whether this is proactive (choosing a reason at post of rejection) or reactive (trying to think back when somebody raises it on meta), we don't really want to add more work there.
- And (related) we don't want *users* to start getting worked up about it, either.

In fact, for many of the above reasons we didn't show *anything* on flag-weight for a while. It *is* a useful measure (and helps prioritise the moderation queue), but it really shouldn't be a distraction from the real every-day usage of the site — discussing language.

I welcome other views, thoughts, suggestions, etc. — even syntax/punctuation critique ;p

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the flags considered valid, as if a flag is considered valid, then the answer being flagged has been closed, deleted, or migrated.
There is effectively no way to understand which flags has been considered invalid or are not yet reviewed.

It would be helpful to understand which flags have been considered invalid, to avoid to flag another question/answer for the same reason.
If the page listing all the flags is changed, then it will be changed in all the SE sites. If you want to really see such feature implemented, you should post the question on meta.stackoverflow.com, where more users can vote it, if they want to see this feature implemented.